# Postgresql - Opposite of string_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql, unnest

I'm looking for a postgresql function that will do the opposite of `string_agg`.

I have a movies table where the tags column contains values such as

```
Action|Adventure|Drama|Horror|Sci-Fi
Action|Horror|Sci-Fi
```

I would like to get a distinct list of tags from this column, for example

```
Action
Adventure
Drama
Horror
Sci-Fi
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `unnest()` and `string_to_array()`:

```
 select unnest(string_to_array(t.col, ','))
 from t
```

Answer (score 4):

You need `string_to_array()` combined with `unnest()`

```
select t.tag
from movies, unnest(string_to_array(tags,'|')) as t(tag)
```