# Parsing out inconsistent data to grab specific year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `TableA` with a column `Years`.  Each row value in this column is formatted as a mix of:

```
2021;2017;2019;2022
```

and

```
2021,2017,2019
```

The number of years listed in each row varies (could be 1, could be 10).

I have a task to pull the latest year for each row.  I am not even sure where to start on this, so I haven't tried anything as of yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736131/postgresql-opposite-of-string-agg). This will let you parse both options, now you just need choose which of the two options you'll need. Try one, if it fails, try the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unnest(string_to_array(...))` to convert the values to rows, then take the max of the expanded column:

```sql
select ID, max(year) as max_year
from (select id, unnest(string_to_array(Years, ';')) as year from TableA) x
group by ID
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/aa238/1).